# Changing class variable in method keyPressed

Tags: java, swing

I want change value of class variable `int keyCode` in overridden method `void keyPressed(KeyEvent key)`. Is there any possible way to do this? When I do something like this: `keyCode = key.getKeyCode()` the variable is changed only inside the function.

Comment: Should edit the question to explain more about what the goal is here.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @paisanco I think I explained really it very clearly - I got class called X, which implements KeyListener, variable in this class `int keyCode` and overridden method `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key)`. In constructor I added a KeyListener, which works fine. In method `keyPressed` I want to change value of variable keyCode, but usual `keyCode = key.getKeyCode()` does not work - variable is not changed outside the function.

Comment: what you are doing is correct: keycode = key.getKeyCode(), and if keycode is in class scope then it should not only change inside the function. You should provide with detail explaination with codes for your problem.

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to know why you want to do this but the choice is yours.